# Error while reindexing solr with rails and mongodb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, sunspot

I am currently using `mongodb` in my rails application. I use `mongoid` as the ODM and I use `sunspot_mongo`. When I try reindex, I get the following error.

```
>rake sunspot:reindex
 rake aborted!
 undefined method 'find_in_batches' for Article:Class
```

I am facing the same issue even if i use `mongo_mapper` instead of `mongoid`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
rake sunspot:mongo:reindex
```

That works. But the reindexing API in sunspot with mongoid is slightly broken.