# Rails sunspot solr reindex error - undefined method 'includes' for Event:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I am following up on a previous question that [I posted a few months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629456/rake-dbseed-error-for-rails-app-using-mongodb-sunspot-solr). I have a slightly different problem now, and I wasn't sure if the old question would get that much visibility from updating it. So, here is my situation:

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application that uses MongoDB, and I have implemented basic Sunspot functionality. Here is some information about my environment

- Rails 3.2.11
- Mongo 2.4.3
- Sunspot 2.0.0
- gem mongo_mapper
- gem sunspot_rails
- gem sunspot_solr
- gem sunspot_mongo_mapper

The three steps I need to run to get solr working are

1. `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`
2. `bundle exec rake db:seed`
3. `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

The first two run without any problems, however I get an error when I try the `reindex` command. This is the stacktrace

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake aborted!
undefined method `includes' for Event:Class
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dynamic_querying.rb:39:in `method_missing'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:254:in `solr_index'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:203:in `solr_reindex'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:20:in `each'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bundler/gems/sunspot_mongo_mapper-b6cf3edca97a/lib/sunspot/mongo_mapper/tasks.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/my_username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/my_username.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It has been a few months since I have worked with solr/sunspot, so I don't really understand the error. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224245/error-while-reindexing-solr-with-rails-and-mongodb), but when I try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489795/10924030) I see this message

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:mongo:reindex
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'sunspot:mongo:reindex'
```

In my stacktrace, what is "Event:Class"? And where can I find the "includes" method?

Any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you have a model named `event.rb`??

Comment: yes, I do. It can be found here (the app is open source)

https://github.com/TheConstructors/QwikStubs/blob/heroku/app/models/event.rb

Comment: in case you havent mention `includes` anywhere in your model, do you have a column name `includes`. Check again if you havent mention `includes` instead of `include` in any function which is either being called from the `event.rb`